# Changing font family of Swal2 at vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, sweetalert

I'm using swal2 (sweetalert2) with vuetify and vue.js,
and having trouble in customizing font family of swal popups.
I've googled but could find only swal ver.1 which is quite different from swal2.

```
<script>
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
...
...

function fireNo(){
    Swal.fire({
          icon: 'warning',
          title: 'titletext',
          showCloseButton: true,
          text: 'texttext',
          focusConfirm: false,
          confirmButtonText: 'buttontext',
      })
    }

//What I've tried: 
<style scoped>
swal2title  {
  font-family: 'fontname'; <- did not work
}
...
```

I've also tried changing font family of 'body' but did not work.
How can I solve this issue? plz help :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try changing classname to swal2title -> swal2-title in your CSS.
Like this

```
.swal2-title{
    font-family: monospace !important;
    color: black;
}
```

We use !important tag to override the styles

Comment: Thanks a lot. actually I've decided to just use v-dialog 